# C# Maintaining a Boolean value at server side

Tags: c#, ajax

On my server side I have the following line of code as a global class variable:

```
       public static bool Test= false;
```

Later in my code I will set the value to **true**;

I have some methods in the same class that rely on the above boolean value (either True, or False). The methods get trigger from an Ajax call from client Side.

**Problem:**
The value is shared among every client as I have declared the Bool as **Static**.

If I remove **Static** then I will get a new problem which the value is not maintained for the same user for his subsequent calls to those methods.

**Question?** How can I make this bool maintain its value for every user.

Comment: Well, you should have persistent storage per user - e.g. a database table keyed by user ID. You really don't want to rely on a) always hitting the same server; b) the server not restarting.

Comment: What kind of application are you running? Forms? MVC.NET?

Comment: @smoksnes, It's an asp.net MVC Application.

Comment: what if you put it in dictionary like `(UserSessionId, bool)` maybe?

Comment: @Benjamin - You _might_ be able to use [Session](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/How-to-create-and-access-447ada98). But then you can only access the value when you got a current Session. I think the comment from Jon Skeet is the better option here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, static means that the property's value will be the same through the life cycle of the application (could be recycled). Read more here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3.aspx

Second, Let's think of your problem as a shared resource that you want all users to access it. Best case you want to store it in a database and have all users to access the database through a Repository pattern or something. If you don't have a database (for some reason) you can store that value in a file.

Comment: I don't have Database, I am thinking to send the bool value to client side, and send it back to server so that it ensure I have got a correct value at all time. But I am wondering if there is a smarter way of doing this?

Comment: Sending it to the client is NOT wise. Save the value in temp file, or see how to cache it in memory (won't be wise either if it's a lot of data) Read more: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff477235.aspx